# Adding string to the front of my domain name

Tags: web-hosting

I have a registered domain and am wondering how to go about adding a string to the front of the domain e.g. string.example.com. Google for example has maps.google.com.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's called a subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on what host you're using.  Most will offer subdomains, however.  generic instructions are to log into your host control panel, and look for an option relating to 'subdomains'.  From there, you should be able to set up subdomains, redirect them, and mess around with them.

If you let me know what host you use, i might be able to find more specific information.

[source](http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/webdesign/what-is-a-subdomain-how-to-create-a-subdomain/)

edit:  since you use cpanel, here you go:
[clicky](https://forums.totalchoicehosting.com/index.php?showtopic=2862)
Basically, it's what i said, but that link gives you exact instructions for using cpanel to set up the subdomain(s)

Answer (score 2):

This would be a function of your DNS and your client machine knowing it's hostname and aliases (and your webserver knowing its aliases). You'd need to properly set up A/CNAME records (you'll want to Google that or consult your DNS provider as there's some debate to the "proper" way to do that, also depending on if you're hosting mail) and then make sure your web server knows all the aliases it is to reply as.

Comment: I am using http://www.crazydomains.com.au and a general web hosting plan. I use cpanel to log in and administer my website if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create either an A or CNAME record in your zone with whomever hosts your DNS. Unless you've configured things to be different than this, your DNS provider is also likely your domain registrar.